# Divide by last row in mutate in Tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

So this is a relatively simple problem, I have a dataset as below

```
df <- structure(list(term = c("(Intercept)", "overall_quality", "overall_costs", 
"wwpf"), estimate = c(0.388607224137536, 0.456477162621961, 0.485612564501229, 
NA), std.error = c(0.499812263278414, 0.0987819420575201, 0.108042289289401, 
NA), statistic = c(0.777506381273137, 4.62105879995918, 4.49465267438447, 
NA), p.value = c(0.440597919486169, 0.0000279867005591494, 0.0000426773877613654, 
NA), average = c(NA, 8.09615384615385, 7.86538461538461, 7.90384615384615
), Elasticity = c(NA, 3.69570933584318, 3.81952959386543, NA)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

I am trying to use below

```
df %>%  mutate(Elasticity= average*estimate/average[nrow(df)])
```

Expected output: https://ibb.co/42ptLXx

basically, divide by last row value & since I am trying to incorporate this in function, I need the method to be dynamic & not hard coded value. 
Please help !

Comment: Try `df %>% mutate_at(-1, ~ ./last(.))`

Comment: Not working @akrun, everything is changing to NA when I do that

Comment: because the last row is `NA`.  Doing calculations with NA result in NA

Comment: For a specific column `df %>% mutate(Elasticity= average*estimate/average[n()])`

Comment: I dont want result for NA row, Please see output screenshot I want result only for overall_quality & overall_cots row which is basically 0.456*8.096/7.90 & 0.4856*7.86/7.90. It is 7.90 which I am struggling to get in tidyverse & keep constant something like we use $F$7 in excel to fix the value

Comment: df %>% mutate(Elasticity= average*estimate/average[n()]) this works, Please post as answer so I can accept. You are genius, expected to get in first try itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `n()` to return the index of last row for subsetting the value of that column

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(Elasticity= average*estimate/average[n()])
```

---

If we need a function (using `rlang_0.4.0`), we can make use `{{..}}` for evaluation

```
f1 <- function(dat, col1, col2) {
        dat %>%
           mutate(Elasticity = {{col1}} * {{col2}}/{{col1}}[n()])
 }

f1(df, average, estimate)
# A tibble: 4 x 7
#  term            estimate std.error statistic    p.value average Elasticity
#  <chr>              <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>
#1 (Intercept)        0.389    0.500      0.778  0.441       NA        NA    
#2 overall_quality    0.456    0.0988     4.62   0.0000280    8.10      0.468
#3 overall_costs      0.486    0.108      4.49   0.0000427    7.87      0.483
#4 wwpf              NA       NA         NA     NA            7.90     NA
```

Comment: Thanks @akrum, this did it. just one minor thing, if I were to use this in function then how would I pass the same.

Comment: @VaibhavSingh. Updated the posst

Comment: @VaibhavSingh. Can you please check if that works for you

Comment: It does, Perfect